# Hmac Signature with Java using secret and payload it not generated correctly

Tags: java, hmac

I have to generate a signature based on the secret key and a payload, I am using this tool to generate the signature:

https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online

This is an example of the text I am sending:

```
 {
      "action": "created",
       "install" : {
           "num": 2,
            "account":{
                "login": "test",
                "type": "User"
             }
        },
        "sender" : {
            "login" : "test",
            "type" : "User"
        }
    }
```

And my secret code: `Encr1pt4do`

and this is my Java code:

```
public class HmacSignature {

    public static String hmacWithJava(String algorithm, String data, String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        return bytesToHex(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte hashByte : bytes) {
            int intVal = 0xff & hashByte;
            if (intVal < 0x10) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal));
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

In java the Payload object applying the toString() method looks like: `Payload{action='created', installation=model.Installation@4c9f8c13, sender=model.User@5ae50ce6}` They are different, I think that is why I am getting different signature values.

The one which is correct is the one generated with: https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to encode your object to JSON first.

Comment: Payload is a Java object

Comment: And `data` is a String.

Comment: oh yes is the payload.toString() method applied

Comment: Yes, that doesn't produce JSON.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here. Let's start with what are you "sending" and how. If it's that json, please say how it's being sent

Comment: Now, I am sending this: {"action":"created","install":{"num":2,"account":{"login":"test","type":"User"}},"sender":{"login":"test","type":"User"}}, but its not formatted in json format, thats why I am not getting the same signature as in the web page generator

Comment: And also seems like the algorithm is case sensitive, because I got a different signature if I change some fields to lower case from or upperCase